# Compact topological group G, X topological space $f: G\times X \to X$ continous...

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

> Let G be a compact topological group and X be a topological space. The map $f:  G\times X \to X$ is continous. Prove that for each open subset $U\subset X $ the set $V=\{x \in X\mid f(x,g)\in U, \forall g\in G\}$ is open in X.

First we know since $f$ is continous, that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X \times G $.
Say $Y \times H=f^{-1}(U)$ since in the product topology a set is open when $Y$ and $H$ are open in there topologies. So $Y=\{x \in X\mid \exists g\in H, f(x,g)\in U\}$ is open in S.

At that point I am not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First $f^{-1}(U)$ does not have to be of the form $Y\times H$. Think of the open ball in $\Bbb R^2$. You should take a look at definition of the product topology. (The products of open sets form a base of the topology.)

Assume $G\times \{x \}$ is contained in $f^{-1}(U)$, then there is also a open neighborhood of $G\times \{x \}$ in $f^{-1}(U)$. I.e. $G\times \{x \} \subset \bigcup V_i\times U_i \subset f^{-1}(U)$ where $V_i\subset G$, $\{x\}\subset U_i$. But since $G$ is compact we know that we can assume the index set to be finite. Thus $G\times (\bigcap U_i ) \subset f^{-1}(U)$ and $(\bigcap U_i )$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ contained in $V$, thus $V$ is open.

Comment: Alright $Y= f^{-1}(U) = \{(x,g) \in X \times G \mid f(x,g) \in U \}$. I guess by the projection you mean the trivial $\pi :  X\times G \to X$? I don't see how $\pi (Y)$ is equal to $V$, wouldnt it be $\{x \in X \mid \exists g \in G, f(x,g)\in U\}$?

Comment: Sorry. You are right.

Comment: @user335236 Guess now it should be fixed?